# Best place for my Java WebStart application to store its files

Tags: java, java-web-start

I'm not really clear on how Java WebStart manages its files.

Should I trust that files saved from my code in the WebStart working directory "." should would stick around?

I'm wondering if a good alternative might be to use a folder under the user's home directory; or perhaps I should let the user configure the data directory to allow for another partition (for backups or space).  Having to do all of this seems to be defeating the purpose of Java WebStart.  At one point, I even deleted the web start application from the Java Console but I as still able to start the application with the network card disabled (offline).

I think I covered every lesson [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html) but they just did not cover this at all.

Answer (score 3):

The `PersistenceService` is part of the JNLP API.  Here is a [demo. of the service](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps). which can be used by sand-boxed apps as well.